# Powershell - Move files into a .ZIP

Tags: powershell, file, zip, archive

I've written a line that will copy files from a directory and place them into a Archive [Date].zip file. This works great but I'd like to **move ** the files into the zip, not copy them.

Is there a way of doing this? I don't want to run another cmd to delete, rather move the fies into a ZIP.

I've tried the following cmd:

```
Compress-Archive -Path "D:\MyFolder\ZIP Logs" -DestinationPath ('D:\MyFolder\ZIP Logs\LOG Archive ' + (Get-date -Format dd.MM.yyyy) + '.zip') -CompressionLevel Optimal
```

However this copies the files into the ZIP and leave the rest of the files outside the newly created ZIP file.

Comment: You can put the `Remove-Item` in the same line with `;` ... short answer, no, not possible in single operation

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use the `Remove-Item`. 
`Compress-Archive` does not support such functionality as deleting the original files. Unfortunately.
If you're not sure how `Remove-Item` works, I suggest to check some of the examples on MS docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3